# Organizational Accounts crashes visual studio in the Asp Net Application Template for vs2013

Tags: azure

Its been a while since I last tried it, was in the preview version of visual studio. But tonight when I wnated to create a demo app using Organizational accounts visual studio just pops saying an error occored after i authenticated myself in the change authentication type diaglog. If i try again it crashes visaul studio. This happens all the time.

I dont know if its my WAAD that is broken or visual studio. What can I do to find out why it fails?

I cant delete old applications either on the portal.

Additional Information.
If I take the "Url for granting access" for one of my old demo apps, it also seems broken.

```
http://g.microsoftonline.com/0AX00en/172?ClientID=a76b286c-332b-45a4-a075-06b46e4eb999&ConsentReturnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fauthz.s-innovations.net
```

Is my WAAD tenant just broken? Do I have to pay for suport on azure just to tell ask them if its broken?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround - Add an organizational account as co-administrator of your azure subscription in the [management console](https://manage.windowsazure.com).

1. Go to your default directory and add a global admin, say admin@foo.onmicrosoft.com
2. Go to your settings and make this admin a co-administrator of your subscription
3. Login to the management console with this newly added organizational account

(refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456328.aspx) for further details)

Then use this account while connecting to azure through visual studio.

Comment: You don't need to add them as a co-administrator. You just need to add a global admin, and use that account when creating the project through Visual Studio.