# Did the Multi Orginazational Accounts authentication get removed from visual studio 2013

Tags: azure, active-directory, visual-studio-2013

Is it my Visual studio 2013 install that is corrupted, or when going from preview to RTM, did they remove the multi organization authentication options with WAAD in the templates?

Related to that, most of my old demos dont work anymore and visual studio is crashing when I try to use the organization signin option. (my other question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575131/organizational-accounts-crashes-visual-studio-in-the-asp-net-application-templat` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was me selecting WebApi project, which do not have it.

Using MVC enables the two other options.